# Linear birth death branching process - expectation equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, stopping-times, birth-death-process

I am currently working on stochastic branching processes, especially linear birth death process. Therefore I am going through a script from university and I have difficulties understanding equation (2.101).

Does anyone has an idea how to show this equation?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: That is the problem. I have no idea. I found some state equations   \begin{equation}
(\lambda_n + \mu_n)P_1 = \lambda_{n-1} P_{n-1} + \mu_{n+1} P_{n+1}  \end{equation}which show similar results without the frac{1}{j}but I do not get how to transform it on the stopping times. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: By "binary branching process" do you mean that the offspring distribution is $\mathbb P(X=0)=d$ and $\mathbb P(X_0=2)=b$ (and I suppose $\mathbb P(X_1=1) = 1 - d - b$)?

Comment: Well, actually it should be $\mathbb P(X=0)=d$ and $\mathbb P(X_0=2)=b$. But I don't see where the $\frac1j$ comes from.

Comment: Yes, that is meant by "binary branching process".

Comment: For everyone who is interested in the solution see "Markov Chain" by J.R. Norris. The chapter is called "Hitting times and absorption probabilities".